# Issue with installing hotfix SQL Server 2008 SP1

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm trying to install a hotfix for SQL Server 2008 SP1 on my Windows 2008 VM machine.
When running the hotfix I keep on getting the following error message:

> TITLE: SQL Server Setup failure.
>   
> A failure was detected for a previous installation, patch, or repair during configuration for features [SQL_BooksOnline_Redist,]. In order to apply this patch package (KB970315), you must resolve any issues with the previous operation that failed. View the summary.txt log to determine why the previous operation failed.
>   
>   Error code 0x84B20001.

Anyone has any idea why I'm receiving this error?

Comment: Why don't you install [Service Pack 3](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27594) + [Cumulative Update 13](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2880350)? I'm trying to think of a good reason to stay on the SP1 branch at this point...

Comment: Conflict with Windows Service pack. Are there any pending updates?